# C# WPF Dynamic List with Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to make a list , example : [List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4VTX.png)

I get datas from SQL, it's possible to scroll if there are more datas.

I need to create this list in WPF.

I need to click on label 00000-0 or label "A" or "F".

I try this :

```
<ListView x:Name="lvDataBinding" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="White">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CL_Operation}">
            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0,3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Background="Transparent">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="5" />
                </Border.Effect>
                <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="50,5" >
                        <!-- <TextBlock Text="Customer" Foreground="#33B6EF" FontSize="20" />-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding strPriorite}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
                        <!-- <TextBlock Text="Location" Foreground="#33B6EF" FontSize="20" />-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding strRetardAvanceText}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2">
                        <!-- <TextBlock Text="Created On" Foreground="#33B6EF" FontSize="20" />-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding strNoOfOp}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="3">
                        <!-- <TextBlock Text="Quantity" Foreground="#33B6EF" FontSize="20" /> -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding strDescriptionOp}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CL_Operation}" >
        <Border BorderThickness = "1" BorderBrush = "Green" Margin = "2" Padding = "5" Width = "900" CornerRadius = "3" >
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <TextBlock Grid.Column = "0" Text = "{Binding Path = strRetardAvanceText}" Background = "LightBlue" />
                <!-- <TextBlock Grid.Column = "0" Text = "{Binding Path = strNoOfOp}" Background = "LightBlue" />-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column = "1" Text = "{Binding Path = strDescriptionOp}" Background = "LightBlue" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column = "2" Text = "{Binding Path = strNoArticle}" FontStyle = "Italic" />
            </Grid >
        </Border >
        <DataTemplate.Triggers >
            <DataTrigger Binding = "{Binding Path = strRetardAvanceText}" Value = "26 jrs" >
                <Setter Property = "ListBoxItem.Foreground" Value = "Red" ></Setter >
            </DataTrigger >
        </DataTemplate.Triggers >
    </DataTemplate >
</Window.Resources >
<Grid >
    <ListBox x:Name = "listBox1" ItemsSource = "{Binding}" />
</Grid >
```

It's a good result but not on two columns, it's a lot of different

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you need to change the `ItemsPanelTemplate`. You can use the `WrapPannel` as a PanelTemplate to have two columns

Comment: If you need exactly two columns, don't use a WrapPanel. Instead, use a UniformGrid and set its Columns property to 2.

Comment: Thank you Clemens, it's great.